# GDK: Immersion causes StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

Recently updated my Glass to XE 17.2, now I can't seem to develop immersions.

The [immersion development](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/immersions) says that immersions are just standard activities. I have the usual stuff in my manifest, with the voice trigger set up like it would be for a live/static card, but instead of pointing to service it points to an activity.

Whenever I try to run the glassware (from a voice command or the menu), it fails to start and I end up with the following log cat:

```
05-26 15:52:16.418: E/StrictMode(1757): class com.google.glass.home.voice.TouchMainMenuActivity; instances=2; limit=1
05-26 15:52:16.418: E/StrictMode(1757): android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class com.google.glass.home.voice.TouchMainMenuActivity; instances=2; limit=1
05-26 15:52:16.418: E/StrictMode(1757):     at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That error isn't related to your application. Perhaps there is another message elsewhere in the log?

Comment: Cleared log, that error is the only error to appear and it shows up right as I start the glassware from the touch menu.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to start the same activity twice, while the system only allows one instance of an activity at a time. Could you show us your manifest?